# Kotlin and Kotlin compiler : version conflict

Tags: android, kotlin

This is something that confuses me for a while now. The kotlin compiler version and Kotlin core library versions won't be compatible most of the times.This is what I have right now which is working

build.gradle(app)

```
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.1.0"
    }
```

build.gradle(project)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

This works, But I've read that the `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` is deprecated and we might not need it. But when we remove that and try to build

`` This version (1.0.0-beta07) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.4.32 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.6.10 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!). ``

But I do not know where this version (**1.0.0-beta07**) came from. If anyone can help me understand what is going on here that will be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

here is where I found a compatibility sheet to find which versions of Kotlin and Kotlin compilers match